# Java data validation on reading file not working properly

Tags: java, file, validation, file-io

I am new to programming and I am trying to create a program in which data can be read from a file and outputted to the console.

I am also trying to check each line of data to ensure it is valid.

Each line should have 5 parts : the title, author, price, publisher and isbn.
I need to get the program to output to the console if any of these are missing and then calculate how many valid and invalid entries there are and output it to a table at the end. 
Below is the code I have written so far could someone please suggest a way I could get this working properly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class libaryAssignment {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] title = new String[100];
    String[] author = new String[100];
    double[] price = new double[100];
    String[] publisher = new String[100];
    String[] isbn = new String[100];
    int invalidcount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String line = "";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    String[] splitLine = new String[100];


    File Fileobject = new File ("valid-invalid.txt");
    if (!Fileobject.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("Error - File does not exist");
        System.exit(0); }

    try {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (Fileobject);

        //Formatting for the outputted data so that is lined up and looks presentable.
        //The % and the number next to it ensure that text is lined up appropriately.
        System.out.println();
        System.out.format("%-20s %5s %16s %15s %13s", "Title", "Author", "Price", "Publisher", "ISBN");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.format("%-20s %5s %16s %15s %13s", "=====", "=====", "=====", "=========", "====");
        System.out.println();



        while(fileReader.hasNext())
        {
            line = fileReader.nextLine();

            String [] splitArray = line.split("-");

            boolean validline = true;

            if(splitArray.length == 5)

                splitArray[0] = splitArray[0].trim();
                splitArray[1] = splitArray[1].trim();
                splitArray[2] = splitArray[2].trim();
                splitArray[3] = splitArray[3].trim();
                splitArray[4] = splitArray[4].trim();

                if(splitArray[0].isEmpty()) {
                    validline = true;
                    System.out.println("Title is missing"); }
                if(splitArray[1].isEmpty()) {
                    validline = true;
                    System.out.println("Author is missing" + line); }
                if(splitArray[2].isEmpty()) {
                    validline = true;
                    System.out.println("Price is missing" + line); }
                else {
                    Double.parseDouble(splitArray[2]);
                }
                if(splitArray[3].isEmpty()) {
                    validline = true;
                    System.out.println("Publisher is missing" + line); }
                if(splitArray[4].isEmpty()) {
                    validline = true;
                    System.out.println("ISBN is missing" + line); }     


                if (validline == true) {
                    title[count]=splitArray[0];
                    author[count]=splitArray[1];
                    price[count]=Double.parseDouble(splitArray[2]);
                    publisher[count]=splitArray[3];
                    isbn[count]=splitArray[4];

                    count++; }
        else {
            invalidcount++; 
        } 
        }
    }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        //Declaring the "PRETTY_PRINT" which does the formatting for the user data that will be output.
        final String PRETTY_PRINT = "%-20s %5s %12.2f %15s %13s";

        //Declaring the Minimum and Maximum variables.
        double minCost = price[0];
        double maxCost = price[0];


        /*for loop which declares "j" and increments it by 1. 
        /*If "j" is less than the books then it increments "j" by one.
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {


            //this is saying if the price is less than "minCost" then the minCost = price. Vice versa for "maxCost".
            if (price[j] < minCost) {
                minCost = price[j];
            }

            if (price[j] > maxCost) {
                maxCost = price[j];
            }

        }

        //Declaring the variable "totalPrice".
        double totalPrice = 0.0;

        //for loop which takes the variable "i" and sets it at 0.
        //Then looks to see if its less than books and increments it by. 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            //this is totalPrice = totalPrice + price to give us the total cost of a book.
            totalPrice += price[i];

            //prints out the user data and inputs into a table.
            System.out.println(String.format(PRETTY_PRINT, title[i], author[i], price[i], publisher[i], isbn[i]));
        }

        //outputs the final table which shows the min and max cost of a book using the variables "minCost" and "maxCost".
        //outputs the average price by dividing by the total price.
        //outputs the number of books by simply displaying the book variable.
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Totals");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total number of books: "+ count);
        System.out.println("Total cost of a book: " + money.format(totalPrice));
        System.out.println("Minimum cost of a book: " + money.format(minCost));
        System.out.println("Maximum cost of a book: " + money.format(maxCost));
        System.out.println("Average cost of a book: " + money.format(totalPrice / count));
        System.out.println("Total number of valid books: " + count);
        System.out.println("Total number of invalid books: " + invalidcount);

        //closing the scanner
        scan.close();



    }

}
```

Below is my test data that has invalid and valid entries in it that I am using to test if my code is working.

> Learning Java - William Lane -12.00 - Wiley - 0811234561
>
> William Stalling - 25.00 - Prentice Hall - 1304086641
>
> OOP programming - Graham Winter - 32.50 - O'Reilly - 0471974555
>
> Windows XP Unwired - Wei Meng Lee - 24.95 - O'Reilly - 0596005369
>
> Programming with Perl - - 19.99 - Wiley - 0476887021
>
> Multimedia Comms - Fred Halsall - 53.99 - Addison Wesley - 0201398184
>
> Guide to Networks - Tamara Dean - 34.50 - Course Tech - 1439055661
>
> A Guide to MySQL -Paul Barry -  - Thomson - 1418834351
>
> CCDA Exam Guide - Anthony Bruno - 49.95 - Cisco Press - 0735700745
>
> Perl and CGI - Elizabeth Castro - 99.50 - - 0201735687
>
> 802.11 Security - Jon Edney - 68.99 - Addison Wesley - 0321136209
>
> Web Design - Hoel Sklar - 9.99 - Course Tech -
>
> Large Scale LANs - Kevin Dooley - 39.00 - O'Reilly - 0596001509
>
> HTML and JavaScript: David  Gast - 12.00 - Wiley 0471383661
>
> Database and Web - Simon Burns - 12Q - Perasons - 0559000412
>
> Wireless Hacks - Rob Weeks - 29.50 - O'Reilly - 0596101442
>
> Trace of Guilt - Neil Barret - 5.99 - Corgi Books - 055X215001

Comment: you have forgotten to add { after splitArray==5 if

Comment: yes i did thank you. but it still doesnt read each line properly and output to the console if a line is invalid

Comment: and you need to add one more to close it before the catch block of FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(splitArray.length == 5)
    {// you have forgotten this

            splitArray[0] = splitArray[0].trim();
        .
        .
        .
    count++; }
        } // you should add this
    else {
        invalidcount++; 
    }
```

there is another issue I do beleive that you are missing a point
if an invalid line in a book is found for exemple a missing title you shouldn't count it as an invalid book ? this depends on your assignment. and you should give it a though

but if I m right on my gess

you have to edit as below :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class libaryAssignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String[] title = new String[100];
        String[] author = new String[100];
        double[] price = new double[100];
        String[] publisher = new String[100];
        String[] isbn = new String[100];
        int invalidcount = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int globalcount=0;
        String line = "";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] splitLine = new String[100];

        File Fileobject = new File("valid-invalid.txt");
        if (!Fileobject.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Error - File does not exist");
            Fileobject.createNewFile();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(Fileobject);

            //Formatting for the outputted data so that is lined up and looks presentable.
            //The % and the number next to it ensure that text is lined up appropriately.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.format("%-20s %5s %16s %15s %13s", "Title", "Author", "Price", "Publisher", "ISBN");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.format("%-20s %5s %16s %15s %13s", "=====", "=====", "=====", "=========", "====");
            System.out.println();

            while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
                globalcount ++;
                line = fileReader.nextLine();

                String[] splitArray = line.split("-");

                boolean validline ;
                validline = splitArray.length == 5;
                if (validline) {

                    splitArray[0] = splitArray[0].trim();
                    splitArray[1] = splitArray[1].trim();
                    splitArray[2] = splitArray[2].trim();
                    splitArray[3] = splitArray[3].trim();
                    splitArray[4] = splitArray[4].trim();

                    if (splitArray[0].isEmpty()) {
                        validline = false;
                        System.out.println("Title is missing\n");
                    }
                    if (splitArray[1].isEmpty()) {
                        validline = false;
                        System.out.println("Author is missing\n" + line);
                    }
                    if (splitArray[2].isEmpty()) {
                        validline = false;
                        System.out.println("Price is missing\n" + line);
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Double.parseDouble(splitArray[2]);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("bad price format :\n" + line);
                            validline = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (splitArray[3].isEmpty()) {
                        validline = false;
                        System.out.println("Publisher is missing\n" + line);
                    }
                    if (splitArray[4].isEmpty()) {
                        validline = false;
                        System.out.println("ISBN is missing\n" + line);
                    }

                    if (validline) {
                        title[count] = splitArray[0];
                        author[count] = splitArray[1];
                        price[count] = Double.parseDouble(splitArray[2]);
                        publisher[count] = splitArray[3];
                        isbn[count] = splitArray[4];

                        count++;
                    } else {
                        invalidcount++;
                    }
                } else {
                    invalidcount++;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        //Declaring the "PRETTY_PRINT" which does the formatting for the user data that will be output.
        final String PRETTY_PRINT = "%-20s %5s %12.2f %15s %13s";

        //Declaring the Minimum and Maximum variables.
        double minCost = price[0];
        double maxCost = price[0];


        /*for loop which declares "j" and increments it by 1. 
        /*If "j" is less than the books then it increments "j" by one.
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {

            //this is saying if the price is less than "minCost" then the minCost = price. Vice versa for "maxCost".
            if (price[j] < minCost) {
                minCost = price[j];
            }

            if (price[j] > maxCost) {
                maxCost = price[j];
            }

        }

        //Declaring the variable "totalPrice".
        double totalPrice = 0.0;

        //for loop which takes the variable "i" and sets it at 0.
        //Then looks to see if its less than books and increments it by. 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            //this is totalPrice = totalPrice + price to give us the total cost of a book.
            totalPrice += price[i];

            //prints out the user data and inputs into a table.
            System.out.println(String.format(PRETTY_PRINT, title[i], author[i], price[i], publisher[i], isbn[i]));
        }

        //outputs the final table which shows the min and max cost of a book using the variables "minCost" and "maxCost".
        //outputs the average price by dividing by the total price.
        //outputs the number of books by simply displaying the book variable.
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Totals");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total number of books: " + globalcount);
        System.out.println("Total cost of a book: " + money.format(totalPrice));
        System.out.println("Minimum cost of a book: " + money.format(minCost));
        System.out.println("Maximum cost of a book: " + money.format(maxCost));
        System.out.println("Average cost of a book: " + money.format(totalPrice / count));
        System.out.println("Total number of valid books: " + count);
        System.out.println("Total number of invalid books: " + invalidcount);

        //closing the scanner
        scan.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what i wanted. Really thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The output of your code is as below after correcting the parenthesis.

> ### Totals
>
> Total number of books: 6
>   Total cost of a book: $177.93
>   Minimum cost of a book: $12.00
>   Maximum cost of a book:
>   $53.99 Average cost of a book: $29.66 Total number of valid books: 6
>   Total number of invalid books: 0

Is this what is expected?